# Why is there no field with one element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2736643/field-with-one-element-in-an-elementary-context/3936582#3936582) but marked as answered and I don’t feel like the question was ever answered, or at least was not clear to me.

I don’t understand why the set consisting only of the element $\{0\}$ along with the usual $+$ and $×$ does not satisfy the criteria, since $0$ acts as both the additive and multiplicative identity.

That is, letting $G = \{0\}$, then

- $∀ g ∈ G, 0+g = g$ and
- $∀ g ∈ G, 0·g = g$ (Since $0·0 = 0$ )

Similarly, it is both its own additive and multiplicative inverse. What is the problem at only the field level, without wishing it satisfy some additional properties for category theory or algebraic/arithmetic geometry?

Comment: One of the axioms of the field is that $0\ne 1$. This is part of the definition. We don't want the $\{0\}$ ring to be a field.

Comment: I wouldn't say $0 \ne 1$ is necessarily part of the definition. I've seen it framed that way sometimes, sure, but other framings I've seen simply imply that, which is just as good IMO.

Comment: It's analogous to why we don't consider $1$ to be a prime number: prime numbers have exactly two divisors, fields have exactly two ideals. These are instances of the "[too simple to be simple](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/too+simple+to+be+simple)" phenomenon.

Comment: For conveneince, most common field axiomatizations exclude models of cardinality $= 1\,$ (either explicitly vua $0\neq 1$ or implicitly as a consequence of other axioms). But this has little to do with the hypothetical [field with one element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element).

Comment: See [Is {0} a field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/427078).

Comment: These reasons seem to be “because it was too simple to be interesting” rather than any sort of fundamental reason. I find this rather unsatisfying off it were true (no offence to the bearers of bad news). It’s akin to saying that the trivial solution, y = 0, of differential equations isn’t a “real” solution because it’s boring, so adjusting the definition to include the clause “other than y = 0”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, let's review: $(F,+,\cdot,0,1)$ is a field if

- $(F,+,0)$ is an abelian group
- $(F \setminus \{0\}, \cdot, 1)$ is an abelian group

What happens if $0 = 1$ and $F$ is the singleton containing that element? Then the latter characteristic is not satisfied, for $F \setminus \{ 0 \} = \varnothing$  yet all groups are nonempty by assumption. (Namely, the axioms of group imply the existence of an element in it, the identity element, so a group is always nonempty.)

Comment: I was under the impression that this (F \ {0}, · ) criterion was in place to address the problem that 0 did not have a multiplicative inverse in the standard examples (ℝ, ℚ, ℂ...)  that fields were modelled after, and that it was either difficult or impossible to define a field in which the additive identity 0, was not absorptive when multiplied, sending everything to 0 ...rather than because 1 was desired to be different from 0. 

Is this not the case?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not, I don't know for sure. All I know is that within this definition, it's obvious no singleton field exist.

Answer (score 5):

Let $K := \{0\}$. Then $K \setminus \{0\}$ cannot be a multiplicative group, since there is no identity element contained in it.